# Translate animation relative to parent using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I have the below code in Java where I create a translate animation relative to the parent. What is the Xamarin equivalent code for this? The Animation class in C# doesn't seem to have these attributes.Any help would be much appreciated.

```
            Animation inFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
```

Comment: I saw you've asked the same question [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83850/translate-animation-relative-to-parent-using-xamarin), did the answer there solve your issue?

Comment: No I still do not understand how to specify the fact that animation takes place relative to parent. These are dynamic components I am dealing with. So I need to do this using code and not xml :( Are there any other ways?

Comment: I've found Xamarin equivalent code for this, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android, attributes like `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT` and `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` are encapsulated into [Android.Views.Animations.Dimension Enumeration](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.Animations.Dimension/).

You can modify your code like this:

```
Animation inFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
Dimension.RelativeToParent, 1.0f,
Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);
```